# How can write the filename of a json file as key value pair for the very same json file?

Tags: python, json, annotations

I have annotation stored in json files for each image but these files do not have the filename of the image as a key in them so I want to enter the file name of these json files as a field in them.

eg:

[image]

`Train1.jpeg.json` should contain the filename field.

```
{"filename":"train1.jpeg"
 "description": "",
 "tags": [],
 "size": {
     "height": 150,
     "width": 150
 },
 "objects": [
     {
         "id": 458095953,
         "classId": 1528218,
         "description": "",
         "geometryType": "polygon",
         "labelerLogin": "shepherd25",
         "createdAt": "2020-06-06T13:58:24.814Z",
         "updatedAt": "2020-06-06T13:58:54.280Z",
         "tags": [],
         "classTitle": "Handgun",
         "points": {
             "exterior": [
                 [
                     36,
                     1
                 ],
                 [
                     34,
                     6
                 ],
                 [
                     31,
                     8
                 ],
                 [
                     34,
                     14
                 ],
                 [
                     25,
                     91
                 ],
                 [
                     28,
                     99
                 ],
                 [
                     28,
                     105
                 ],
                 [
                     43,
                     110
                 ],
                 [
                     68,
                     110
                 ],
                 [
                     70,
                     99
                 ],
                 [
                     70,
                     99
                 ],
                 [
                     76,
                     98
                 ],
                 [
                     94,
                     19
                 ],
                 [
                     102,
                     12
                 ],
                 [
                     99,
                     0
                 ]
             ],
             "interior": []
         }
     }
 ]
}
```

I am trying to make these files valid for coco format.

Comment: What is the input and output?

Comment: I have not used these annotation for training yet.

Comment: In order for anyone to help, at a minimum this *information* must be provided — so I suggest you [edit] your question and add it.